# Can somebody tell me why this command doesn't work?

Tags: math-mode, errors

```
$\frac{1-(-$\frac{1}{2}^t$) }{$\frac{3}{2}$}$
```

For some reason it gives me an error, something about a `Missing \endgroup`, be warned I'm new to Latex.

Comment: You are using mathmode within mathmode: `$\frac{1-(-\frac{1}{2}^t)}{\frac{3}{2}}$` is better

Comment: TeX doesn't really enjoy when you tell it to enter math mode once it's already in math mode. So just drop the internal math mode switches.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. And please quote complete error messages.

Answer (score 5):

You are using too many `$` and hence forcing tex to enter math mode when it is already in math mode. Hence remove all internal `$`. Also the super script `t` should go outside the parenthesis. Assuming that you are in display mode, I have added `\displaystyle`. If not, remove it and also `\big`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle \frac{1-\big(-\frac{1}{2}\big)^t}{\frac{3}{2}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Remove inner `$`.

```
$\frac{1-(-\frac{1}{2}^t)}{\frac{3}{2}}$
```

should do the trick. The following is just a suggestion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\dfrac{1-\left(-\frac{1}{2}^t\right)}{\frac{3}{2}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]